# Adding new column to dataframe based on column with blank rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks as following with multiple blank rows:

```
 date   hour     Temp

6/1/2017    0:00    64
6/7/2017    22:00   63
6/7/2017    23:00   62

6/2/2017    0:00    62
6/2/2017    1:00    60
6/8/2017    23:00   65

6/6/2017    0:00    64
6/6/2017    1:00    64
6/12/2017   22:00   78
6/12/2017   23:00   76
```

I want to create the following:

```
 date   hour     Temp   newDate

6/1/2017    0:00    64  6/1/2017
6/7/2017    22:00   63  6/1/2017
6/7/2017    23:00   62  6/1/2017

6/2/2017    0:00    62  6/2/2017
6/2/2017    1:00    60  6/2/2017
6/8/2017    23:00   65  6/2/2017

6/6/2017    0:00    64  6/6/2017
6/6/2017    1:00    64  6/6/2017
6/12/2017   22:00   78  6/6/2017
6/12/2017   23:00   76  6/6/2017
```

Where a new column has been created with first date from `date` column right after the blank rows.

I am trying to create for loop but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will, no doubt, be a smart Pandas solution. But here's a solution using `itertools.groupby`. I assume that your blank rows consist of `NaN` items, and leverage the fact that `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

# group by items being NaN
grouper = groupby(df['date'], key=lambda x: x==x)

# extract first item, multiply and chain
chainer = chain.from_iterable([next(j)]*(len(list(j))+1) for _, j in grouper)

# assign to new series
df['newDate'] = list(chainer)

print(df)

         date   hour  Temp   newDate
0         NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
1    6/1/2017   0:00  64.0  6/1/2017
2    6/7/2017  22:00  63.0  6/1/2017
3    6/7/2017  23:00  62.0  6/1/2017
4         NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
5    6/2/2017   0:00  62.0  6/2/2017
6    6/2/2017   1:00  60.0  6/2/2017
7    6/8/2017  23:00  65.0  6/2/2017
8         NaN    NaN   NaN       NaN
9    6/6/2017   0:00  64.0  6/6/2017
10   6/6/2017   1:00  64.0  6/6/2017
11  6/12/2017  22:00  78.0  6/6/2017
12  6/12/2017  23:00  76.0  6/6/2017
```